# Уровни логирования в log4J

Tags: java, junit, log4j2

Здравствуйте, имеется программа с юнит тестированием. Логирование происходит и при выполнении программы и при юнит - тестировании. В файле конфигурации Log4J.xml выставлен уровень логирования TRACE. В юнит тестах вывожу в логи сообщения с использованием уровня DEBUG, в программе TRACE. Когда запускаю юнит тесты в логи выводятся еще и сообщения с классов программы (логично, что при юнит тестировании вызываются методы классов программы - поэтому и идет не нужная запись). Как этого избежать? Спасибо!